# Clone or copy a method in an object (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, object

Suppose I have an object A:

```
var A = {
    'parameter': "Dura lex sed lex.",
    'function_a': function (new_type) {
        console.log ("It's working!");
    }
};
```

Then, suppose I also an object B:

```
var B = {
    'parameter': "Veni vidi vici!"
};
```

What I need is a simple way to dynamically create a method `function_b()` inside the object B without copy/clone the parameter, of the object A, ("Dura lex sed lex.") in the object B and to preserve the parameter ("Veni vidi vici!") of the object B.

How can I do it?

Comment: `_proto` ? property.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki No

Comment: Just assign `B.function_b = A.function_a;`?

Comment: "Vini vidi vici!" is not what Caesar said... It's "veni" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```js
var A = {
    'parameter': "Dura lex sed lex.",
    'function_a': function (new_type) {
        console.log ("It's working!");
    }
};

var B = {
    'parameter': "Vini vidi vici!"
};

var clone = function(origin, target, prefix) {
  Object.keys(origin).forEach(function(key) {
    if (!target.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (key.indexOf("function_") > -1) {
        target["function_" + prefix] = origin[key];
      }
    }
  });
}

clone(A, B, "b");

console.log(B);
B.function_b();
```

Comment: Much too complicated. And that `hasOwnProperty` check is good for nothing.

Comment: @Bergi I supose OP wants a dynamic function, not a hard code snippet.

Comment: @Bergi also, he wants to preserve the duplicated keys, that is why I added `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: We don't know. Better post a comment to ask for clarification instead of a guess at an answer.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing easier and more quickly?

Comment: @S.P.H.I.N.X no.

Answer (score 3):

try it:

```
B['function_b'] = A['function_a'];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question, but I think you want something like this:

```
B.function_b = function(whatever) {
  console.log('it works!');
};
```